# Eclipse and Intellij showing wrong java method declaration. How can I fix it?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

in java the `Thread.join(long millis)` method is not a synchronized method. also you can see this method declaration form this link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join-long- but eclipse and idea showing this method as synchronized. you can look at the following picture to what I want to mean. by the way, I am using java 9 in eclipse
how can I fix this problem in eclipse ?

[image]

Comment: I think your question is actually "why does JavaDoc not show whether a method is synchronized?".

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, no I clicked the `Open Declaration`  button in right click context menu. and eclipse showed this method as synchronized in the Thread.java editor tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse and IntelliJ are showing you the actual code, and thus are correct by defintion.  The apparent mismatch is because Javadoc doesn't show whether a method is `synchronized`.

This was a deliberate design decision; see this [bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4078855).  Quoting:

> It's important for the developer to know whether it's safe for multiple threads
>   to operate on an object concurrently,  However, this synchronization can be
>   done either in public methods or in private methods, and the Java Platform API
>   spec should not declare one to be preferred over the other.  A licensee should
>   be able to achieve synchronization internally if they wish.
>
> Therefore, the general description of a class should mention whether the class is thread-safe or not.  Individual method descriptions that are exceptions should mention that they are exceptions.

The TL;DR is that `synchronized` is an implementation detail, not part of the method contract.  So Javadoc doesn't show it.

Comment: So I should look at the declaration of method from javadoc not from "Open Declaration" menu. Right ?

Comment: @1JustOnly1 - It depends on what question you're trying to answer.  "How to use it?" vs. "How is it implemented?".